# Scipy installation windows 10

Tags: windows, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, windows-10

I have some difficulties trying to install Scipy for Python 3.5 on a Windows 10 machine and I hope I can find some help here. So here is what I have done so far.

I have downloaded the numpy+mkl for python 3.5 and 64bit version as well as the scipy0.18.1 for the same versions, from Gohlke's website

I installed the numpy+mkl whl with:
python -m pip install numpy-1.11.2+mkl-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
all goes well.
then I install the scipy package the same way like:
python -m pip install scipy-0.18.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
This also completes. 
However, when I try to run python afterwards I get the following error:

`Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\scipy\io\__init__.py" , line 97, in <module>
  File "C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\scipy\io\matlab\__init__.py", line 13 in <module>
  File "C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\scipy\io\matlab\mio.py", line 8 in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'`

I also get a pop-up that Python has stopped working. 
I have tried a different order in which I installed the packages, but all lead to the error mentioned when Scipy is installed. 
I also installed did this on a windows 7 machine and there it works.

Does anybody have any idea what causes this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I also had some issues. So I just installed [Anaconda3](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) insted of python directly.

Comment: Thanks, I know that works. It is just that I want to know why this happens.